# LogCat throwing thousands of message "Created Orientation..." on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-logcat

Eclipse was working just fine but suddenly is throwing thousands of message that says "Created Orientation =..." Tag: edu.mit.ll..

Any idea? Attached a screenshoot.

[image: Eclipse LogCat]

Comment: Seems like something in an app (from edu.mit.ll) you are running are logging loads of messages.

Comment: Did the orientation of the device change when this happened? Which device are you on? Is your application attempting to do anything "special" with regards to the orientation?

Comment: @Jave - I don't have any application from edu.mit.ll; I believe that the problem is the device.

Comment: @Tim - It happens everytime I connect the HTC Incredible to Eclipse.  No application is running and my application does not do any special to the orientation either.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably correct then, problems is something with the device. That will happen from time to time. I don't have experience with that specific device but I definitely have worked on devices where the Log is getting constantly spammed by something in the system. The Tag filters in eclipse help to week out the non-sense when you are trying to debug your applications.

If you expand the Tag column what is the full package name? Is it an application that you are working on? Is it something that was installed from the market? Or does it just exist (i.e. came pre-loaded on the device.)